# Keeping the cursor to stay there, after inserting a value in Access form

Tags: vba, ms-access

How can I keep the cursor in the current position after inserting data into the form using Macro access Please. 
I have a program with tables and forms. I can also import data from excel into access. From the Drop down menu, I can also insert thousand records. But the cursor position goes to the top. So I have to scroll down to see newly inserted rows.

Appreciated for any suggestion.

Comment: use `End` button on keyboard maybe?

Comment: Sort records DESCENDING or code in VBA `Docmd.GoToRecord , , acLast`

Comment: _So I have to scroll down to see newly inserted rows._ Which means, that the cursor should _not_ stay ...

Comment: Save the ID of the last record in the form before you import data. After the import, use the Form.Recordset.FindFirst method to find the saved ID. Your cursor will be just before the new data.